# Internal DSLs implementation techniques

Tags: dsl

I want to ask about Domain Specific Languages. Internal DSL based on Martin Fowler's classification. (In my opinion Internal DSL is like building an API!!)

what are some common techniques used to implement Internal DSLs.

Another question, Internal DSLs are what so called fluent interfaces, embedded languages ?

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Many of these questions are answered well in DSLs in Action, http://debasishg.blogspot.com/, so you may want to look at the book written by this author.

To answer the rest of your questions really depends on what type of DSL you are thinking about writing, even an internal DSL can be varied, where it can be a simple DSL for date/time, up to something that is basically a language written in your target language.

For a nice discussion on what DSL it you can look at http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2005/12/what_is_a_dsl.html.

I would suggest you put your planning in up front, and decide on how you expect it to be used, as going back and fixing a bad design when it is being used will be a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks .I am reading about DSLs and I want to write something like survey, lets say implementing Internal DSLs techniques.. I don't want it hard, just as simple as it can be .. Unfortunately all the resources provided advanced examples .. I dont want to invent something or take a problem and try to make a DSL for it, its just as simple as writing a survey about something in DSLs. For me I need an idea to start working on .. Anything about DSLs like comparisons or techniques, but not about external DSLs because I dont want to get enrolled with compilers issues and grammars or building parsers.

Comment: So who is your target audience?  If it is just other programmers than a fluent API may be a good starting point. If it is users then you may need to make it simpler.  A simple one for end-users would be a simple math DSL, perhaps, as you can make it more complicated later, if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Fowler article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/InternalDslStyle.html) already explains the concept quite well (and he defines the term, so his definition is right, by definition :-)

The key concept here is meta-programming: you use the host language's meta-programming facilities to make it look like you've introduced new keywords. Where possible/reasonable, you use compile-time evaluation, elsewhere you use stack walks to inject code into calling scopes.

Strictly speaking, it is just an API. However, (according to me), it's an internal DSL if doing it in Pascal had required a proper language extension.

Comment: Exactly .. Thats what I believe .. But I am getting tired about this issue because all the resources are focusing on Fowler's work in which I could not find it great to understand ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently reading Fowler's new book *Domain Specific Languages* and it is layed out like any Pattern reference, with various common patterns for implementing various types/parts of DSLs, along with their back-end "Semantic Model"s.  Its breadth is amazing, with just enough depth to show some good examples, that is, it discusses concepts/issues across various orthogonal views of implementing/defining a DSL.

He worked very hard at limiting the depth, otherwise the number of pages would have squared, not just doubled.  Highly recommended (so far - I'm thru chapter 10 where he discusses a small set of commonly known DSLs, e.g. CSS, Make, et.al., just to help you get a better understanding of the terminology and "patterns" glossed over by the first 9 chapters - there are 57 chapters, most of which discuss various DSL "patterns").